# Algorithm for better Big O complexity

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Could someone please help me with this question?:
**how can you limit the input data to achieve a better Big O complexity? Describe an algorithm for handling this limited data to find if there are any duplicates. What is the Big O complexity?**

By limit the input data, we mean the array size e.g. n=100 (array contains 100 integers) and also; the array is unsorted by default but could be implemented in the algorithm.

The worst case complexity which i got is **O (N^2) = N * ((N + 1)/2)** in the case of an unsorted array of size n.

I got that by using nested loops (outer loop used for n-1 iterations- used to iterate on each value in the array- and the inner loop used for comparison to check to see if duplicates exist) and repeated the process until the outer loop terminates.

Comment: Arrays don't have a big-O complexity, algorithms do. You hint at it, but don't mention the actual problem your algorithm should solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the solution right in front of you. As you state, if the array is unsorted, finding duplicates is O(N^2). But if the array is sorted, you can do it in O(N). So sort the array first, which can be done in O(N.Log(N)).

An algorithm that first sorts and then find the duplicates can thus be done in O(N.Log(N) + N), which is O(N.Log(N)).

UPDATE:

As Amir points out: you can use a hash table. Since inserting and searching in a hash table is O(1), you can do this in a single loop, yielding O(N) time complexity.

However, your question is about "limited input data". So if you limit your input data to sorted arrays, you can reduce the complexity to O(N). To be precise, if you know that the array is sorted (this is your limitation), than a single loop that compares every element to its successor(s) will find the duplicates.

If the array is not sorted, you need an outer loop over all elements but the last, and an inner loop over all the remaining elements. If the array is sorted, you don't need the inner loop, just compare to the next element. That is the "reduction" of the algorithm, resulting in a "reduction" of O(N^2) to O(N).

Comment: Krish Vandermotten and Amir. Thanks for your help. I finally got a solution on getting a better Big O complexity than O(N^2). I will implement the O(n.log(n)) algorithm since it doesn't seem much of a hassle whereas i don't even know how the algorithm for the hash starts.

Comment: Kris Vandermotten... sorry but could you extend on how i could reduce the complexity to O(N)... could that be done by once the array is sorted, i would use a single loop to compare the integers to check to see if there are duplicates and this would be O(n) but how could i sort the array so that it doesn't affect the big o complexity? I don't know if what i wrote makes sense but could you please extend/ elaborate on how i can reduce the complexity to O(n) if i have an array (e.g. of 100 integers). thanks

Comment: @user3418449 See my updated answer. I'm not going to give you actual code, there has to be some exercise left for you ;-)

Comment: kris vandermotten... it's all good. I just needed that, the code i can implement myself. I was lost with the algorithm but since you've helped with that, i'll get the code done myself. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to sort and then remove duplicates, but you need an additional memory

Pseudocode:

```
remDups(arr,arr2)

   Sort(arr); // O(nlogn)
   arr2[0] = arr[0];
   j=1;
   foreach(i+1 to arr.len : i++) //O(n)
   {
      if(arr[i-1] == arr[i]) continue;
      arr1[j++] = arr[i];
   }
```

O(nlogn)

You can use, `HashTable`method